# HTML : Keeping specific blocks of text indented without new lines

Tags: html

I work with a configurable software that can accept HTML when making captions for fields for user input.

The fields have to match a specific format that is out of my control to change.

They need to look like this:

```
4. a. Text goes here and when it word
      wraps it needs to keep the indent
      with the text like so
   b. This is a separate field, with its 
      own caption but needs the same 
      indentation as above
5.    Another separate caption, but this
      line does not have sub sections
```

Each line of the document is its own caption, and needs to be left aligned regardless of value. The html needs to be simple enough that if another developer came to change something it wouldn't be difficult to understand what is happening. The closest I have gotten to a desired result is using &nbsp but that isn't pretty for someone who may need to reconfigure it later. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Are you getting these values from some sort of data source, or are these manually entered?

Comment: I am simply inputting what the caption should say on a pre-formatted document. One that can take html as an input for field captions. I have tried various options with lists, though it seems to be overly complex to make every single item in a list an entire list on its own, while needing to set start vaues based on which number I am on, and also needing to clear the automatic padding that comes with <ul>. 

In other words, I need the easiest to read way of getting the result shown in the code block above, using 3 separate html compatible captions.

Comment: The easiest way is to do just what you did in the question (well, SO did it via Markdown, but you know what I mean): use a `<pre>` element and format the string that way. It will be shown in a monospace font, but thems the breaks...

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the requirement that you need 3 separate captions? My answer doesn't work for that...

Comment: Well, now it does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's a way of doing it, but it does require using the `start` attribute of an `ol` to make sure the numbers work the way you want, if it will be three separate HTML units.

For comparison, I've shown what it looks like to just use a `pre` element and spaces to get a similar look. Note that you could style the `pre` to use a non-monospace font, but then you lose the alignment.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px
}

#container>ol {
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
}

#container>ol>li>ol {
  list-style: lower-alpha;
  margin-left: -1.25em;
}

#container>ol.empty>li {
  list-style: none;
}

#container>ol>li.no-sub {
  padding-left: 1.25em;
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<pre>
    4. a. Text goes here and when it word
          wraps it needs to keep the indent
          with the text like so
       b. This is a separate field, with its 
          own caption but needs the same 
          indentation as above
    5.    Another separate caption, but this
          line does not have sub sections
</pre>

<div id="container">
  <ol start="4">
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>Text goes here and when it word wraps it needs to keep the indent with the text like so</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol start="4" class="empty">
    <li>
      <ol start="2">
        <li>This is a separate field, with its own caption but needs the same indentation as above</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <ol start="5">
    <li class="no-sub">Another separate caption, but this line does not have sub sections</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! While this is exactly the correct answer. Unfortunately the software in which it is being embedded into does not handle it well. The change in font also makes it so that I can not use it due to uniformity constraints.

In other words, the real problem is that I am over constrained, but in most cases you are spot on, thank you.

Comment: Well, sorry that you're so constrained. I've been there though, it ain't easy. Good luck.